# Monad Map with two values in Java Functional Programming

Tags: java, functional-programming, option-type, monads

Forgive me if this is a basic question in FP. Let's consider Optional monad. I know I can use `map` to transform an `Optional` to another `Optional` based on a function (which will be called if optional has a value). But what if I have a function with two inputs, not one?

For example:

```
var data = Optional.of(100);
var result = data.map(x -> x * 2); //all good!
```

But what about:

```
int getData(Connection conn, int data) { ... }

var data = Optional.of(100);
var connection = getOptionalDataConnection();
var result = data.map(i -> getData(connection?, i));  //this does not work as the getData function only accepts non-optionals
```

I'm sure there is a term for this in FP world I'm just not familiar with it. But the idea is I have a map function which accepts "two" inputs, rather than one. And I want a helper/utility/... that will call my function if both inputs are there. But if any of them is "empty" should return `Optional.empty()`.

What is this called and does Java support this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is this called and does Java support this?

This is called a [monad](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2022/03/28/monads), and yes, Java supports it via the [flatMap function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) (monadic *bind*). Here demonstrated with just two optional integers:

```
var xo = Optional.of(100);
var yo = Optional.of(2);
var result = xo.flatMap(x -> yo.map(y -> x * y));
```

In this example, `result` is an `Optional` value holding the integer `200`.

For the particular example in the OP, you actually don't need a monad, since using the capabilities of the [Maybe/Optional applicative functor](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/10/29/the-maybe-applicative-functor) would be sufficient. I'm not well-versed in the Java ecosystem, however, and I don't see any *apply*-like methods in the API documentation. You could probably write it yourself, but my experience from Java's cousin language C# tells me that applicative functors are awkward in such languages.

Answer (score 3):

Before we delve into this, cripes my spidey senses are tingling. This:

> But if any of them is "empty" should return Optional.empty().

Is such a bad idea. It's objectively a pretty big loss in robustness and productivity if you replace 50 NullPointerException errors, which at least point directly at where the problem lies and ensures execution does not continue, with 10 'huh, weird - this code.. it... did nothing for some reason' errors. Those 10 errors can have very nasty side-effects (because code continues), and take **way** more than 5x as long as those NPEs to fix, so you're in a worse place with more time spent bughunting. And this kind of casual defaulting ('eh, just do nothing!') is exactly how you get to that nasty place.

So, you know - delving perhaps slightly too far into opinion for SO's tastes, but, oof. Don't do any of this. I'm not quite sure it's a great idea in general, but *in java* this is no good.

NB: Because generics and optional is bad and all that, I've replaced all use of `int` with `Integer` because this isn't going to properly work without doing that due to the limitations of primitives and generics.

### Partial application

The answer you're looking for is partial application.

What you currently have is a function that accepts a `Connection` and an `Integer` and returns an `Integer`. What you need is a function that accepts an `Optional<Connection>`, an `Integer` and returns an `Optional<Integer>`. Specifically, the `Optional<Connection>` is provided, but the Integer is an input. So let's make that then:

```
Optional<Connection> connection = getOptionalDataConnection();
Function<Integer, Optional<Integer>> f = i -> connection.map(c -> Optional.of(getData(c, i)));
```

Armed with this function, we can do the job easily:

```
Optional<Connection> connection = getOptionalDataConnection();
Function<Integer, Optional<Integer>> f = i -> connection.map(c -> Optional.of(getData(c, i)));

Optional<Integer> data = Optional.of(100);
var result = data.flatMap(i -> f.apply(i));
```

It's rather a lot of code and to my sensitivities, the actual essence is mostly lost here. But, it's what's there in java (specifically, Optional's `flatMap`). You can write utility methods that turn optionals into flatmappable functions.

Let's put it together:

```
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.*;

class Example {
  public static <U, V, R> Optional<R> compose(
    Optional<U> first, Optional<V> second,
    BiFunction<U, V, R> func) {

    Function<V, Optional<R>> f = v -> first.map(u -> func.apply(u, v));
    return second.flatMap(v -> f.apply(v));
  }

  public static String make(String a, Integer b) {
    return a + ", " + b;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Optional<String> as = Optional.of("Hello");
    Optional<Integer> bs = Optional.of(100);
    Optional<String> an = Optional.empty();
    Optional<Integer> bn = Optional.empty();

    BiFunction<String, Integer, String> func = Example::make;
    System.out.println(compose(as, bs, func));
    System.out.println(compose(as, bn, func));
    System.out.println(compose(an, bs, func));
    System.out.println(compose(an, bn, func));
  }
}
```

Related terminology that is somewhat relevant to this case is 'currying'. The more general principle of wrapping all sorts of stuff in Optional, I'm not sure that even has a name.